# How do you request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Android?

Tags: android

From Android Docs, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access

*"An app can request All files access from the user by doing the following:*

*Declare the **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in the manifest.*

*Use the [**ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)  intent action to direct users to a system settings page where they can enable the following option for your app: Allow access to manage all files."*

### What I've tried

The only way I know how to request permissions is with `ActivityCompat`. I've tried:

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION},1);`

and

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);`

Neither of which do anything.

The Android docs are extensive but not exactly the most welcoming for newcomers. I understand intents, and know they can be used to switch between activities, but I don't know what an "intent action" is and how it can be used to request permissions

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Kotlin:

```
    val uri = Uri.parse("package:${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}")

    startActivity(
      Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
        uri
      )
    )
```

(from [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/RawPaths))

You are probably used to an implicit `Intent`. The docs are asking you to use an explicit `Intent`, one with an action string and, in this case, a `Uri`. The `Uri` will have the `package` scheme and identify your app by its application ID.

That code snippet will start a system-supplied activity that, in theory, will let the user opt into granting your app the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: I have been taking a Udemy course on Android which covered Intents but not in this way.
I tried
            ```Uri foo = Uri.parse("package:"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, foo));```
and got a fatal error, ```Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION dat=package:com.example.storagecleaner }```

Comment: @ChrisA: It is rather disappointing that Udemy does not cover implicit `Intents`. With regards to your crash, an implicit `Intent` might not match an available activity, so this crash can happen. Wrapping your `startActivity()` call in `try`/`catch` and gracefully handling the exception will be needed. Also, note that this permission and `Intent` action are only relevant on Android 11+, so this is guaranteed to fail on Android 10 and below. If you are trying this on Android 11, what is the device make and model that you are testing on?

Comment: My AVD was API 29 (Android 10). I then tried on API 30 (which is confusingly marked as 10+ in some places, and 11 in others). Nexus 6 API 30. Still get the same error

Comment: @ChrisA: I just set up a fresh Android 11/API 30 emulator, and my sample app launches this activity without issue (if you run the app, click the infinity-symbol toolbar button). So, I am uncertain what is different about your app or emulator that is causing a problem.

Comment: I also started from scratch, just added the permission to the manifest, and the lines from my first comment in. No dice. Could you possibly share the entire project on Git please? Just to allow me to rule out the code and narrow it down to a config/emulator problem.

(I don't see an infinity symbol, just the green "play" button to run)

Comment: @ChrisA: "Could you possibly share the entire project on Git please?" -- um, I did already. Here is the link again: https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/RawPaths "I don't see an infinity symbol, just the green "play" button to run" -- sorry, I meant in the toolbar in the app, not in the IDE.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I thought you'd created a brand new project. Reading again it was the originally linked project but a new emulator. I notice your app used `ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`, not `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`. I changed that in my app and it worked a charm :)

Comment: @ChrisA: Ah! Yes, I missed that subtle difference as well. `ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` brings you to a page specific to your app, and is typically the one that we would use for what you are seeking. I think `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` leads to a screen listing all apps that have or have requested `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Glad you have it working!

Comment: Yeah. The docs say ALL_FILES, but I think APP_ALL_FILES is what I really wanted all along. Don't know why the former failed but don't mind. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ChrisA: "Don't know why the former failed but don't mind" -- `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` does not take a `Uri`. If you add one anyway, that will confuse the system for identifying matching activities, which is why you got the `ActivityNotFoundException`. If you started `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` without any `Uri`, it should work, though the `ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` one (with the `Uri`) is probably what you want.

Comment: @ChrisA: And BTW, [that permission right now makes your app ineligible for distribution on the Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65885987/115145). Even once that total ban is lifted, I expect that you will need to fill out a form explaining why your app needs this capability.

Comment: For the time being it's just something I'm trying to develop for myself to do certain cleanup tasks on my storage and also for a practice project. Thanks for the heads up in any case!

Comment: I have been taking a Udemy course on Android which covered Intents but not in this way. I tried Uri foo = Uri.parse("package:"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);             startActivity(new Intent(Settings. ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, foo)); and got a fatal error, Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings. ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION dat=package:com.example.wear}

Comment: Isn't this supported by the wear app?

Comment: @hongdeveloper: It would not surprise me at all if some specialized Android environments, like Wear OS or Android TV, do not offer that Settings screen.

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you saying that Wear OS doesn't even provide a simple download function?

Comment: @hongdeveloper: No, I am saying that perhaps Wear OS does not offer that Settings screen.

Comment: crash on android 10

Comment: Works great on Android 11

Comment: Replace `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` with `BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME` since `APPLICATION_ID` is deprecated

Comment: @FahadAlduraibi: `APPLICATION_ID` is still valid for app modules.

Comment: Just a side note: `Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)` is an explicit intent. You are explicitly specifying which component to launch, rather than describing an action to be handled by an eligible component as you would with an implicit intent.

Answer (score 20):

You can create an intent like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
```

Now, you can launch this intent with startActivityForResult.

```
final static int APP_STORAGE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 501; // Any value
startActivityForResult(intent, APP_STORAGE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In your onActivityResult method, you can check whether the user granted you the permission or not.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == APP_STORAGE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE && Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
        // Permission granted. Now resume your workflow.
    }
}
```

You can also do this with the new ActivityResultAPI by launching the activity with :

```
// Initialize the variable in before activity creation is complete.
val storagePermissionResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult(),
            ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult?> {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
                {
                    // Permission granted. Now resume your workflow.
                }
            })
// launch the above intent.
storagePermissionResultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

Also, make sure that you add this permission entry in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Comment: Environment.isExternalStorageManager cannot be resolved. Should I upgrade gradle version? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to have minimum compile and target SDK version as 30.

Answer (score 19):

If Uri will be used in Intent, Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION can be used instead of Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION.

```
if(SDK_INT >= 30){
if(!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Permission needed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Settings", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception ex){
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
        try {
            var intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + packageName))
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Logger.d(TAG, e.message)
            var intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` and `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` are different.
Both of them can direct user to system settings page.
The difference is:

`ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`, with this action, direct user to the package ("`package:<package-name>`") setting page.

`ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`, this action direct user to app list. All apps which want to manage all files will show in that list.

Comment: You almost solved all my problem. I have been searching for your kind of answer for last three days. So, when I install my app now I am calling getPermission flutter function to call MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. 

however, earlier I was not able to list all folder in emulated/storage/0 but now nothing comes up.  Post allowing 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

anything needs change

Answer (score 1):

1 Did you add uses-permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?
like :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2 You can refer this github library:
https://github.com/getActivity/XXPermissions
It wraped the api of google sdk, and provide a simple way to apply the permissions.

Comment: 1. I did for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as stipulated in the docs 2. 我都看不懂

Comment: Oh, maybe its README is in Chinese. But you can try to translate it with google. It provides a more simple way for permissions in Android 11, you can check the code directly. You can also find other android lib for permissions in github.

Comment: instead of criticize people who answer I would appreciate if you post link to documentation.

Comment: Docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent Environment = new 
Intent().setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
    .setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));

if (Environment.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
    startActivity(Environment);
}
```