# After adding manage external storage permission, I can not upload APK to google store

Tags: android, apk

I have an application on Google play store, I updated the code to support Android 11 OS, I'm using the storage of mobile by this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

When I try to upload the APK on Google store, this problem appears

> Your APK or Android App Bundle requests the 'android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permission, which Google Play doesn't support yet.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the api level to less than 30 because due to covid-19 all permission has stopped.
This temporary uploading restriction only affects apps that both target Android 11 (API level 30) and request the All files access permission.

Comment: It's still possible to upload apps with the permission even after the 5th May has passed (they said it would work after the 5th May: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-all-files-access-permission)

Answer (score 2):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9956427?hl=en-GB

I think either remove the permission, or just wait for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like , the upload of apks that target OS 11 is temporarily blocked until early 2021 as described in this link , check it out :

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9956427?hl=en