# upload to google playstore still failed in May 2021: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: google-play

With `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest, i can write Excel files successfully except in Android 11. I added the permission  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and in the Android 11 emulator,  it worked perfectly well. However, when i uploaded to the play store, my app was rejected because the play store does not support MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. According to [similar query in Jan 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65885987/after-adding-manage-external-storage-permission-i-can-not-upload-apk-to-google) this, a user adviced that we wait till May 5 2021.

I read this google article here on [guidance oh how to Use of All files access MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission (effective May 5, 2021)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955) but during the upload process, no form is displayed for me to fill.

Is there anything i am missing? Android 11 devices are now so many and writing Excel files to the user's device is one of the core functions of the app.