# Alternative of MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use other alternatives of the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to download images in external storage, as it is not allowing apk to upload on the Play store

Comment: You can just download your file to public Download directory as always. Or to other public directories.

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65885987/after-adding-manage-external-storage-permission-i-can-not-upload-apk-to-google

Comment: I had tried all these but not able to find solution