# Android File.listFiles() returns only subdirectories

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to get all files and subdirectories in directory and show their names. This is the code I use:

```
File internalStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
File[] files = internalStorageDir.listFiles();
ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i< files.length; i++){fileNames.add(files[i].getName());}
```

The specified directory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) contains files and subdirectories, but listFiles() only returns subdirectories. What's wrong with this code? Permission to read external storage has already been granted.

Comment: Can you print the specific path you're accessing and compare with ls output on that same path?

Comment: What version of Android are testing on? BTW, you can simplify this code by replacing `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())` with just `new Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: I tried to test it on an AVD with Android 10 and a real device with Android 11. The result is the same.

Comment: It is quite normal that the root of external storage only contains public directories.

Comment: `File internalStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());` you can simplify this code: `File internalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` ;-)

Comment: Yes, but in my case, there are a couple of files in the root of the external storage.

Comment: Do you have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes

Comment: `there are a couple of files in the root of the external storage` Please tell Android version of used device and tell who owns these files: your app or did they land in another way on your device?

Comment: @blackapps Android 10, files were downloaded from the internet.

Comment: Who did that? `and tell who owns these files: your app or did they land in another way on your device?`

Comment: @blackapps Device user. My application does not own these files.

Comment: On an Android 10 device they should be visible. But... very strange that they would be downloaded to root of external storage and not to the Download folder. Not visible on an Android 11 device... well not yet for your aap... unless..

Comment: @blackapps I tested my app on Android 11 and found my code works, but there is another problem: it only shows media files. Maybe there are some restrictions in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault, I missed something. In Android 11, you can only access media files. In my case, the files in external storage were not media files, so they were not displayed. But after changing the target api to 29 (Android 10) everything works fine. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Comment: anyone who need to read any files in external storage, can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68168979/5892421