# Request permission manage all files on android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

How can I request permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on android 11 (wear os)

I try this code:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXj1D.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV1Zg.png)

But it alway allow only while using app. Is anyone try it ? How can I grant allow all the time permission.

Comment: what do you mean by "allow only while using app"? you need to ask permissions in wearable device, are you doing that?  follow this link https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/permissions

Comment: I would like to request permission for all time but it does not work.

Comment: I would like to request permission for all time but it does not work. Request permissions on Wear OS always show "Allow" or "Deny". If I choose "Allow", it will allow while using app.

Comment: I try to use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876736/how-do-you-request-manage-external-storage-permission-in-android. But error : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

Comment: Regarding on your latest exception provided, you may try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250814/how-to-obtain-manage-external-storage-permission

Comment: Thank @Enowneb. But it error : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION }

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have?